# How can I set up a Tor HS so that the first hop always goes through my relay?

Tags: configuration, onion-services

I'm interested in hosting a Hidden service on a KVM host that I control. I'd like the first hop from the hidden service to also go through a relay running on the same KVM host. What settings do I need to make this happen?

usefule information for others also found [here](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/11751/how-do-i-make-sure-my-tor-hidden-service-gets-trustworthy-entry-guards)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `torrc` file of your relay, you need to set `EntryNodes fingerprint` and `StrictNodes 1` This will tell Tor to *only* use the set entry node to build circuits.

Comment: This seemed to be what I wanted, thanks. When you say relay, do you mean the HS node or the relay node?                                                     And do you have any idea how this affects security?

Comment: This would be the configuration for the HS node. As far as security goes, you'll always be connecting to a "trusted" guard that you run. However, your relay node IP is public, and if the HS node only connects through your relay, it might be possible to learn or guess its IP address through correlation attacks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do that by directing your HS router to use your relay as a bridge.
First add these lines to `torrc` of your relay to set it up as a bridge:

```
ORPort <some port>
BridgeRelay 1
Exitpolicy reject *:*
```

Then configure the router that hosts your HS to use your bridge:

```
UseBridges 1
Bridge <bridge line of your relay>
```

There is no guarantee that rendezvous circuits will always go through the bridges with `UseBridges` on. Tor may behave unexpectedly. Furthermore, an adversary could correlate your HS without effort since there are almost no hidden services behind a bridge.

Comment: Could you provide an explanation of *how* to do this?

Comment: @AndrewLott Answer edited with further explanation.